# "The doctor took/examine my pulse."

Tags: verbs, word-in-context

Suppose,  a doctor came to my house to check my pulse.

Then, what would be the correct verb:

> The doctor took/examine my pulse.

In the sentence above (in bold), which one should be the appropriate verb? "took"? or "examine"?

Answer (score 2):

[Took](https://www.mayoclinic.org/how-to-take-pulse/art-20482581).

Were I to run across "examine my pulse", I would, out of context, expect it to involve some sort of test where, perhaps, you lay down, or exercised, so that the examiner was seeing how your pulse reacted to situations.  "Took" is usual for simple, ordinary processes that led to one simple and determinate answer.

Comment: Thank you so much <3